# In Greek mythology, who are the Younger Charites?

Tags: greek, gods

I know about the Charites, the goddesses Aglaea, Euphrosyne, and Thalia. But there is apparently a younger Charites group?

Comment: What references have you found to this group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like much of greek mythology, it all seems to be a bit of a mess and it depends on which long dead spirit of an ancient poet you ask. There is disagreement on both the number of [Charites/Graces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charites) and their names.

The commonly known Charites, as presented by the poet Hesiod, are the daughters of Zeus and Eurynome: [Aglaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaea), [Euphrosyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphrosyne), and [Thalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalia_(Grace))

There is also [Pasithea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasithea_(Charites)), a daughter of Hera and Dionysus, who is referred to by Homer as "one of the younger Graces" in the [Iliad](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134%3Abook%3D14%3Acard%3D242). According to wikipedia she's considered a sister of the three above.

The poet Nonnus, on the other hand, names the three Charites as: Pasithea, Peitho and Aglaia. So we lost Euphrosyne and Thalia, and gained Peitho. The Spartans were more spartan, and made do with two: Cleta and Phaenna.

And then there are the daughters of Aglaea and Hephaestus: [Philophrosyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philophrosyne), [Euthenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthenia), [Eupheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eupheme_(deity)), and [Eucleia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucleia). Who are also considered "members of the younger Charites" (according to wikipedia, but lacking clear citation)

So depending on where you encountered the term "younger Charites", it might refer to the daughters of Aglaea, or any of the younger members of the Charites (however many there were - and which may or may not include the daughters of Aglaea).